# SharedPreferences in multiple classes

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I am not very familiar with java coding but I wanted to make my own app.

I want to use `SharedPreferences` to store some values across different activities/classes as is shown in multiple tutorials (and also questions on this site) but when I try to read them in another activity which is in another class I get random numbers like 2131361821.

The user has to fill out a `textview` field with id `direction_1000` so I get a wind direction at 1000ft via the class GetWind.

If I store this value as an `int` in `SharedPreference` all works fine but If I want to pass this value to the class `InputNavData` and display it over there via the `int` `PHI` and `String` `phi` I get this strange value.

Can someone help me to solve this? Sorry in advance for the messy code and question but as I said it's all very new to me.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.navigationcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.navigationcalculator.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Agree button */
public void wind_input(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetWind.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Input Navigation Data button */
public void input_nav_data(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InputNavData.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Calculate Data button */
public void calculate_data(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculateData.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**GetWind**

```
package com.example.navigationcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static com.example.navigationcalculator.R.id.direction_1000;

public class GetWind extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myfirstapp.sharedPref";

public final static String DIR_1000 = "com.example.myfirstapp.DIR_1000";
public final static String SPEED_1000 = "com.example.myfirstapp.SPEED_1000";



SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_wind);

}

//Read all wind speeds and directions and put them in a shared preferences file
public void input_nav_data(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InputNavData.class);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    startActivity(intent);

    // 1000 feet
    EditText dir_1000 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direction_1000);
    int direction_1000 = Integer.parseInt(dir_1000.getText().toString());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(DIR_1000,direction_1000);
    editor.commit();

    int shared_dir_1000 = sharedpreferences.getInt(PREFS_NAME,direction_1000);
    String SD1000 = String.valueOf(shared_dir_1000);
    Log.d("direction 1000",SD1000);

}
}
```

**InputNavData**

```
package com.example.navigationcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static com.example.navigationcalculator.GetWind.PREFS_NAME;
import static com.example.navigationcalculator.R.id.direction_1000;



public class InputNavData extends Activity {

public final static String altitude_static_string = "com.example.myfirstapp.altitude";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_nav_data);

}

//Read all navigation data and pass them through as a string to activity CalculateData
public void calculate_data(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculateData.class);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    startActivity(intent);

    // Read the actual altitude
    EditText alt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altitude);
    int altitude = Integer.parseInt(alt.getText().toString());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(altitude_static_string,altitude);
    editor.commit();

    int shared_altitude = sharedpreferences.getInt(PREFS_NAME,altitude);
    String SALT = String.valueOf(shared_altitude);
    Log.d("altitude",SALT);

    int PHI = sharedpreferences.getInt(PREFS_NAME,direction_1000);
    String phi = String.valueOf(PHI);
    Log.d("dir 1000 in inputnavdata",phi);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from some `Activity` to another one ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I try to pass the data (direction_1000) from Activity InputNavData to Activity CalculateData via shared references.

Comment: Don't use  `SharedPreferences` to just pass data from activity to another, instead send your data with the `intent`, if you don't know how I can help you

Comment: I know how to pass data via an intent from one activity to another but I actually want the data from the first activity to be available to several other activities/ classes (amongst which CalculateData), that is why I want to use shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `input_nav_data` and `calculate_data` methods.

It's because what the flow should be:

1. Get shared preference
2. Store values inside shared preference.
3. Commit
4. Start activity

What you are doing is

1. Get shared preference
2. Start activity
3. Store values inside shared preference.
4. Commit

`calculate_data`

```
public void calculate_data(View view) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculateData.class);
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Read the actual altitude 
 EditText alt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altitude);
 int altitude = Integer.parseInt(alt.getText().toString());
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
 editor.putInt(altitude_static_string, altitude);
 editor.commit();
 int shared_altitude = sharedpreferences.getInt(PREFS_NAME, altitude);
 String SALT = String.valueOf(shared_altitude);
 Log.d("altitude", SALT);
 int PHI = sharedpreferences.getInt(PREFS_NAME, direction_1000);
 String phi = String.valueOf(PHI);
 Log.d("dir 1000 in inputnavdata", phi);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have put the startActivity(intent) at the end but the result remains the same unfortunately...
I guess it has to do something with the `import static com.example.navigationcalculator.R.id.direction_1000; ` but I am not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Just to pass data you could use :

```
 int x = 0;
 intent.putExtra("xx", x);
```

And then get it in other class by :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
xy= intent.getIntExtra("xx",0);
```